# Can the claim check pattern be used with Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In most readying around kafka streams it is not recommended to you request/response within a kafka stream application, or more generally interacting with external system synchronously within a stream topology.

However i have a case where i need consume a stream of claims that reference documents stored in S3 (one for each claim) and process it to produce small record. Essentially a candidate for a FlatMap.

I wonder if anyone have experience with this kind of scenario using kafka streams and what has been the outcome.

If discouraged, what would be an alternative solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no built-in support for external call, so it's challenging to get it right (but I also know that a lot of user still do it anyway :))

Please checkout https://www.confluent.io/events/current/2023/the-nuts-and-bolts-of-kafka-streams-an-architectural-deep-dive/ -- it explains the internal architecture of Kafka Streams, and should help to understand why external call are a challenge, and why blocking calls can destabilize the system.

For your case, it seems you could buffer the input data into a state-store, and do a "best effort" fetching (maybe also using punctuations), and after you did receive the data and successfully processed it, purge the input record from the store again.

There is of course a question of ordering arising. Not sure how important it is for your use case to preserve record order from the input topic...